# Can protobuf encode a probability distribution?

Tags: protocol-buffers

Let's say I have this

```
message Game
{
    string name = 1;
    repeated float probability = 2;
}
```

where the `probability` fields represent a distribution. This means each value must be non-negative and the sum must be 1.

Is there a better way to use protobuf for this (e.g. something like a `non_negative_float` or something that puts a boundary on the sum of values)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there are no unsigned floating point types in Protocol Buffers, nor any automatically-imposed constraints like this.

You may want to add constraints in your business code when you deserialize a `Game` - with awareness that the sum of the `float` approximations to the fractional results may not be *exactly* 1.0. You'll need some form of tolerance there.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to securely do this with just one type. You could go a step further and say do this:

```
{
    string name = 1;
    repeated uint32 probability = 2;
    uint32 divisor = 3;
}
```

The trick is to multiply your float with a big number, 1000 000 or so, and later divide it again. That would give you safety but also overhead.

Comment: How does this solution add any more guarantees compared to the solution I have in the question?

Comment: The probabilities in my case cannot be negative unless you decide to convert negative number to a uint32. To the case of sum that is always done with validation.

Comment: Ah, right! I missed that. I don't think it is worth the overhead / potential errors, but I appreciate the answer (+1)

Comment: My advice is build a validator after you parse the data so you do not need to worry what if. It is a potentially big overhead but it saves you a lot of diagnostics in later stages of development and system testing.